# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

My app gives me this error when using this onclicklistener

```
private OnClickListener btn_Config_Onclick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Name", selected_Name);
        bundle.putString("Image", selected_Image);

        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Configure.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

The class for configure is here: http://pastebin.com/njMa9buE

and the complete error here: http://pastebin.com/REemSken

I have been looking over everything and cant for the life of me find whats wrong, everything is correctly defined in the manifest etc.
Hoping fresh eyes will find the issue

Comment: Are all your Activities correctly defined in the Manifest file?

Comment: Post Logcat errors, I m sure the NPE is in Configure.class

Comment: have you declared configure class in manifest file

Comment: Yes i already said its defined in the manifest, and the complete logcat of the error is here http://pastebin.com/REemSken

Comment: Which one is Configure.java:59 code line?

Comment: Try this:Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this, Configure.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `chk_RunVNC`. It is `null`. You never assign anything to it. So this throws a `NullPointerException` in `onCreate()`:

```
chk_RunVNC.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chk_RunVNC_OnCheckedChange);
```